# Regex doesn`t find matches

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new to using regex and am trying to find the following text :

```
<div class="name">

    <a href="/rd/?S=1401191307481569663391991831690328817&I=&DS=42639&T=55&U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spokeo.com%2Fmapview%2Fperson%2F18643819031%3Fpx%3D%26piplstart%3D%26q%3DJoe%2BHenderson%2C%2BPhoenix%2C%2BAZ%26g%3Dname_piplv2_scd_city01&P=">
        <span class="highlight"> … </span>

         T 

        <span class="highlight"> … </span>

        , E Flower St, 

        <span class="highlight"> … </span>

        , 

        <span class="highlight"> … </span>

        , 

        <span class="highlight"> … </span>

        , 50 years old

    </a>

</div>
<div class="url">

    www.spokeo.com/mapview/person/18643819031?px=&piplstart=&q=Joe+Hend...

</div>
```

The expression I came up with is :

```
("<div class=\"name\">[\S\s]+</div><div class=\"url\">[\S\s]+</div>")
```

However no matches are found. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use an HTML parser.

Comment: [Obligatory Cthulhu reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693). Don't parse HTML with regex; use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: What language or tool are you using? Regex isn't universally the same.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow: +1, that's hilarious every time :))

Comment: @Peter Lazarov: No seriously, don't do it. Use a real parser.

Comment: @PeterLazarov Then use a Python HTML parsing library, like BeautifulSoup. Do NOT parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Is there a reason HTML parsing using regex is so frowned upon?

Comment: Did you read the link given by @DoorknobofSnow?

Comment: HTML is not a regular language and is impossible to parse with regex. Consider how you would parse `<div><img alt='</div>'/></div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a new line here:

```
</div>
<div class="url">
```

But you don't have one in your regex:

```
         |
         V
...</div><div...
```

Try adding `\s*` there (well assuming `\s` includes new lines in Python, and the `div`'s actually always follow on one another with nothing but whitespace in between).

But, as already mentioned, [using regex to parse HTML is playing with fire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693).